# jQuery 1.5 AJAX call fails with "invalid label" for JSON requests

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-1.5

I've just upgraded from version 1.4 to version 1.5 of jQuery, and now my AJAX calls always fail with the "invalid label" error.

An example request is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async: false
    , dataType: "json"
    , error: function (xhr, status, error) { ... }
    , success: function (data, status, xhr) { ... }
    , type: "post"
    , url: "ajax/request.asp"
});
```

On the net I found this error is raised when the returned JSON is not wrapped with jQuery's callback (e.g. `jQuery1234({ "something": "abcd" })`.

The problem is I'm returning a JSON, not a JSONP (and I state it in the AJAX request), so why I must specify a callback in the returned JSON?

The [1.5 changelog](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/) says nothing about this... (Or it's me who can't read?)

Update:

This is an example of a not working JSON:

```
{
   "esito":"Ok",
   "centriCosto":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "descrizione":"Colazione"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "descrizione":"Pranzo"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "descrizione":"Cena"
      }
   ]
}
```

And this is the same callback-wrapped working JSON:

```
jQuery1502710949228847014_1296739130498({
   "esito":"Ok",
   "centriCosto":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "descrizione":"Colazione"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "descrizione":"Pranzo"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "descrizione":"Cena"
      }
   ]
})
```

By the way, Firebug says both of them are valid JSONs (and he's very picky about correctness).

Comment: It could be an issue with the json itself, I have noticed that since 1.4 JQ has been much more stringent about JSON structure. My first JSON project from '07 started failing when i upgraded my JQ, I opened the JSON output and was floored at how poorly I structured it. Can you post the JSON?

Comment: @picus: Nope, I validate my JSON against multiple validators and it's ok. If I implement the JSONP callback it starts working again, so it's not a problem with the format.

Comment: @picus: I've added an example of a not working and a working JSON.

Comment: @kappa Try adding a space after `"esito":`.

Comment: @lonesomeday : I've luckily found out what's happening, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886525/jquery-1-5-ajax-call-fails-with-invalid-label-for-json-requests/4886800#4886800).

Comment: Do you **really** need `async: false`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: When performing a choice I need to show some boxes, and the AJAX is not triggered every time, it depends on some conditions, so instead of duplicating the box-showing code I opted for `async: false` (it's an Intranet application an half-second delay won't matter).

Comment: Ok.. for intranet it's probably acceptable. For internet it's not really good as it hangs the whole browser (at least in some browsers).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the hell is happening.

jQuery's [Validation plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is not compatible with jQuery 1.5 (see [one](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8118) and [two](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getjson-and-jquery-1-5)), removing the plug-in yields to the right behaviour.

If someone else has this problem, there's a patch in the plug-in's repository: [link](https://github.com/bigfix/jquery-validation/commit/9aa53f9241224ba349f9fe1b2c801be0f431b63b)

Comment: My coworker just spent the last hour trying to figure out a similar issue.  We upgraded to 1.6 and no more conflict with the validation plug-in. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I actually ran into similar problem but it appears to be related to this bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8398

It is not necessarily related to jQuery-validate and it took me a while to figure things out. It turns out that jQuery 1.5 is modifying subsequent ajax calls for json to jsonp which leads to this error.

I fixed it by following one of the workarounds suggested in the bug change history and placing the following code somewhere before my ajax calls are made:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   jsonp: null,
   jsonpCallback: null
});
```

Should fix any problems for other ajax requests too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible workaround for those with the validator plugin.

dataType: "text json"

Works like a charm.  Don't ask me why.  On chrome, you can see a jquery syntax error parsing the ":" on the json return.  And make no mistake about it, the return is valid json.  I didn't try it but I suspect Tom's answer above will also work.

Answer (score 1):

try:
Did a quick search for json in jquery-1.5.js and found this on row 6905:

// Detect, normalize options and install callbacks for jsonp requests

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp", function( s, originalSettings, dataIsString /* internal */ ) {
```

removing the `"json"` from first argument will add correct behavior when spec. `dataType:"json"`

Answer (score 1):

If your server-side code is relying on the callback name beginning with "jsonp", you may have a problem.  The callback name prefix was changed to "jQuery" in version 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is fixed now in v1.6 - had the same issue after upgrading to ver 1.5.1 & after upgrading to 1.6 the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to jquery 1.7 solves it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
$.post("...", {},
        function(data) {

      // dont forget to add below lines         

         },"json");
```