# Remote validation of jquery validation plugin is breaking in jquery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

We are using [jquery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin in our project. Recently we have upgraded our jquery version to 1.5. It reasonably increased the speed and performance of our project. But remote validations are breaking with this version.

Actually, the remote servlet sending the expected response. But in client side, it was omitted by the script.

Is there any other people with this same issue?

Any idea about, how i can overcome this problem?

Any suggestions would be appreciative!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem is just in the strong support of ajax protocol by jquery 1.5.

Try to use something like this on the server side of your application(php):

```
$check = 'true';
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=windows-1251");
$result = $_REQUEST['callback'].'('.$check.')';
echo $result;
```

**To do this in Java**
 [refer this](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/jquery-1-5-broke-my-validation-302)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately i have no experience in php. Can you explain it in java!? From my servlet(java) i am returning true or false(both are string).

Comment: Can you plz refer this http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/jquery-1-5-broke-my-validation-302  It may solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886525/jquery-1-5-ajax-call-fails-with-invalid-label-for-json-requests/4886800#4886800 here is the solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues#issue/36